# How to elegantly get full url from the ActivatedRouteSnapshot?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router-guards

In some of my Angular route guards, I want to set up the "next" path, to redirect to after successful login.

So, the ordinary guard `canActivate` function signature looks like this:

```
public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
  // ...blah
  return true;
}
```

The `route` parameter is an instance of `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`.

Previously to get the "next" URL I was just getting it from the `route.url`. This works just fine, as long as there are no children routes.

My example URL is `/search/advanced?query_hash=1221d3b57f5616ee16ce70fdc78907ab`, where `advanced` is a child route of a `search`.

Child routes can be found in `route.children`, but iterating over these children (especially there might be multiple levels) and combining the URL this way seems awkward and ugly.

What I'm interested in is contained in `route._routerState.url` property (being a string, on the bottom of the image below), but it's a "private" variable.

Am I missing something? How can one elegantly get the full (with children paths) URL from the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`? Angular version is 5.1.

[image]

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There's no ready to use function from Angular router to achieve that, so I wrote them:

```
function getResolvedUrl(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
    return route.pathFromRoot
        .map(v => v.url.map(segment => segment.toString()).join('/'))
        .join('/');
}

function getConfiguredUrl(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
    return '/' + route.pathFromRoot
        .filter(v => v.routeConfig)
        .map(v => v.routeConfig!.path)
        .join('/');
}
```

Example output when `route` is from `ProjectComponent`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'project', component: ProjectListComponent, children: [
            {path: ':id', component: ProjectComponent}
        ]
    },
];
getResolvedUrl(route) => /project/id1
getConfiguredUrl(route) => /project/:id
```

Comment: @marc-j-schmidt great function. I found that when you have feature modules with child routes `.map` can return segments that are empty strings. Kind of like the first element you get in the array. So the array can look like `['', 'manager', '', 'users']` resulting in a `resolvedUrl` that looks like `/manager//users`. I hacked it with a `.replace('//','/')` to deduplicate for now. Probably a `filter` to prevent empty strings in the first place and prepending the final `resolvedUrl` with a `/` may be the better design choice. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, adding a filter checking for empty paths should be sufficient.

Comment: This has been working great for me for a long time - but now I need to get the URL when there are auxiliary routes. This method just squishes them all together without the parenthesis. Can't believe there isn't a build in way :-/

Comment: You can use flatMap to simplify getResolvedUrl a bit.

`route.pathFromRoot.flatMap(v => v.url).join('/');`

Answer (score 53):

try this to get it from RouterStateSnapshot

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
      console.log(state.url)
      ...
```

Comment: This don't anser the question, which stated how to get the URL from 'ActivatedRouteSnapshot'. This interface not only used in `canActivated()` but in many other places for example  `shouldReuseRoute(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot)`  there you don't have the 2nd parameter 'state' so how to get the URL from ActivatedRouteSnapshot??

Comment: yes, it works for me - window.location.origin + state.url

Comment: While this didn't answer the question, it was perfect for what I was looking. Thanks for putting this up!

Comment: Since the question asked about `CanActivate.canActivate()`, this is a perfectly good solution to the questions problem. The questions title does not fit the proposed problem.

Answer (score 6):

There already is a ready to use function in Angular to achieve this [createUrlTreeFromSnapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/createUrlTreeFromSnapshot):

Firstly, you can now return just the `UrlTree` from the `canActivate` method. And secondly, if you want to compose a URL as string, you can use `UrlSerializer` API which should e.g. reflect hash vs. path URL strategies:

```js
import { createUrlTreeFromSnapshot, UrlSerializer } from '@angular/router';

// ...

class MyClass {

    constructor(private urlSerializer: UrlSerializer) {}

    getResolvedUrl(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        return this.urlSerializer.serialize(
            createUrlTreeFromSnapshot(route.snapshot, ['.'])
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure when this was added, but it does not appear to be in Angular 12, which I acknowledge is a pretty old version.

Answer (score 5):

The solution of Marc for his `getResolvedUrl` does not return query parameters.
The function below has added support for queryparameters.

```
getResolvedUrl(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
  let url = route.pathFromRoot.map((v) => v.url.map((segment) => segment.toString()).join('/')).join('/');
  const queryParam = route.queryParamMap;
  if (queryParam.keys.length > 0) {
    url += '?' + queryParam.keys.map(key => queryParam.getAll(key).map(value => key + '=' + value).join('&')).join('&');
  }
  return url;
}
```