# Forcing a navigation in every ngOnInit (conditionally and implicitly) in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, router

I have a variable *token* in my service. At the moment, it governs whether I'm authenticated or not. When the application needs to chck if the user is signed in, it asks the app `!!this.security.token` and reacts accordingly. That needs to occur in every secured component.

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (!this.security.token)
    this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
  ...
}
```

I wonder if there's a better method handling this. I'm comparing the HTTP interceptor that adds headers and logging to my GETs and POSTs, which is mighty convenient. However, googling *interceptor angular router* gave only hits on HTTP injecting, nothing about controlling the routing.

Is there a way to intercept the call to each component checking that *token* still exists?

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private security: SecurityService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  id: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.security.token)
      this.router.navigate(["/"]);

    this.route.params
      .subscribe(suc => this.id = suc.id);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Comment: Angular Provides Route Guards to protect your components

Comment: @JBNizet Aha, my ignorance was at blame here. Once I used *guard* intead of *interceptor*, the list of findings was much more adequate. Thanks! Interesting that Angular team used two different names for the same concept (well, "the same'ish").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously mentioned by others, Angular provides [route guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) to check if a particular user is enabled or not to navigate on that route.

You can also implement your custom validation on your routes.

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-guards)

[Random blog example](https://juristr.com/blog/2018/11/better-route-guard-redirects/)

[Convenience example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53429547/1525840)

Comment: I took the liberty to alter your answer a bit to make it more complete for the future visitors. Hope it's fine by you.