# Custom Page Permission using Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular11, angular-router-guards

I am working on an application in which I am implementing custom permission. There is subscription-based permission that I can't check in auth guard which will be static and I have implemented helper for permission which checks for route and then check it in user subscription for that route and then redirected to any of the pages on role permission. It is working fine but I need a better approach to implement it with clean code. Here is my implementation

> Home Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Location } from '@angular/common';   
import { AuthService } from "src/app/services/apiServices/auth.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private readonly location: Location, private readonly authService : AuthService ) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getPermission(this.location.path());
  }
}
```

> Auth Service Code

```
getPermission(currentRoute: string) {
    this.userPermissions = this.loggedInUserSubscriptionDetails$.subscribe(sub => {
      if (sub) {
        if (sub.MenuPermissioList.map(x => x.url).indexOf(currentRoute) === -1) {
          this.router.navigate(["/finance-analysis/not-authorized"]);
          return;
        }else{
          console.log('exists');
        }
      }
    });

  }
```

This code is basically getting a current location path and then checking that path in subscription **MenuPermissioList** if it exists then it allows to open up the page otherwise it redirected to unauthorized.

I don't want to use this code **data : {roles: [ApplicationRolesEnum.CompanyAdmin]}** because I have to add or remove roles from data to allow that user for a specific page and it is basically static binding. Here I have added this check and it is working fine but my permission may vary from user to user. Which makes it difficult to maintain.

```
     {
        path: "home",
        canActivate: [AuthGuard, SubscriptionGuard],data : {roles: [ApplicationRolesEnum.CompanyAdmin, ApplicationRolesEnum.ExternalUser]},
        loadChildren: () => import("src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module").then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try following approach. I did not test it now and have written it off the top of my head but it is based on an approach I used in one project.

Basically you would still use a Guard for this but load the permissions from your service dynamically and based on them either let the user activate the page or redirect to the Unauthorized page. CanActivate subscribes to the Observable for you so you don't have to manage any subscription manually.

```js
import { AuthService } from "src/app/services/apiServices/auth.service";


@Injectable()
export class SubscriptionGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private readonly router: Router,
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
  ) { }

  canActivate(activatedRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.loggedInUserSubscriptionDetails$.pipe(
      take(1),
      map((sub) => {
        if (!sub) {
          return false;
        }
        return sub.MenuPermissioList.map(x => x.url).includes(routerState.url);
      }),
      tap(hasPermission => hasPermission ? undefined : this.router.navigate(['/finance-analysis/not-authorized']))
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: changed the way of extracting current url after discussion in comments.

Comment: Sorry doesn't help as the browser got stuck on canActivate and it ran unlimited time

Comment: If sub.MenuPermissionList.map return false then it run unlimited time and keep on running doesn't redirected to un-authorized page

Comment: Hm you could try use switchMap instead of tap as the last operator like this ```switchMap(hasPermission => hasPermission ? of(true) : from(this.router.navigate(['/finance-analysis/not-authorized'])))```

Comment: No luck with switchmap too. Basically the problem when it start return false then it keep on going

Comment: It's pity it doesn't work for you. If you would provide a working Stackblitz which reconstructs this problem I will look once more into it but for now it's hard to debug it blindly.

Comment: You can try the last one ```map(hasPermission => hasPermission ? hasPermission : this.router.createUrlTree(['/finance-analysis/not-authorized']))```

Comment: Is there any other way with using map still the same

Comment: It worked thank you so much I have figure it out It was a little mistake I was making now going good.

Comment: Ok, cool! Did the version from answer work without changes or one of those from the comments?

Comment: But I got one problem here in the URL I am getting **/calculator/interest-accrual** and it always return false

Comment: I am getting these links from the database

Comment: getPathFromRoot return this **//compliance**

Comment: Try to log out what do you get from getPathFromRoot and if it is the same like in the MenuPermissioList

Comment: Like for the calculator I am getting **//calculator**

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250361/how-to-elegantly-get-full-url-from-the-activatedroutesnapshot) if it helps

Comment: I have done it using state.url it fetch me the whole URL... state: RouterStateSnapshot